# Open Source Applications using distributed caching solutions

Tags: ehcache, distributed-computing, distributed-caching, hazelcast, infinispan

I am looking for a list of open source Java applications which use the distributed caching solutions like ehcache, infinispan, Hazelcast etc?

For my research I am making changes in locking behavior of these caches and trying to understand the performance changes. To substantiate my results I want to use some production level real world applications, not some dummy cache access pattern generator. Can someone provide a list of 5-6 good open source projects which uses these products in distributed settings?

Otherwise can someone provide a list of open source distributed computing based java projects which require a high level of concurrency?

Comment: Not sure you will find any of them. In real world projects leveraging distributed caching solutions are enough advanced to not do it just for fun. So this information should be for internal use only. I'd go to work in such a project if I really need this. Take a look at the 'Our Clients' page on the vendor site and send them your CV :)

Comment: Thanks Viktor, I also thought same. But Fuad do suggested the Hazelcast based applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list of several open source projects that use Hazelcast

- Apache Tuscany
- Alfresco
- OrientDB
- vert.x
- Mozilla metrics: Several projects like baghera, socorro and etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fuad, I will go through code and find the Hazelcast implementation in these projects. Any idea about other caches?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a list of some open source projects using Infinispan:

- JBoss Application Server 7
- Hibernate ORM (2LC)
- Hibernate OGM
- Modeshape
- Apache Camel
- CapeDwarf

Comment: - Hibernate Search uses Infinispan for real-time replication of Apache Lucene indexes. - Scarlet uses Infinispan to provide high availability of JIRA (the issue tracker)